# how to get process file name from PID in MacOS?

Tags: mac-osx, process, pid

Is it possible to get a file name of a process using PID? ps  displays a lot of useful information about a process, but not a hint about a process executable file location.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One way of getting the process's binary location is to use `lsof` and `grep` for the first `txt` segment. For example, in the shell to see what binary the shell is, use the shell's PID in place of `$$`.

```
$ lsof -p $$ | grep txt
bash    78228 blair  txt    REG   14,2   1244928   6568359 /bin/bash
bash    78228 blair  txt    REG   14,2   1059792  23699809 /usr/lib/dyld
bash    78228 blair  txt    REG   14,2 136368128  81751398 /private/var/db/dyld/dyld_shared_cache_i386
```

You can see that the shell is using `/bin/bash`.

This technique works if the process was launched using an absolute or relative path.  For example, going into one shell and running

```
$ sleep 1234567
```

and using `ps` in another shell only shows how it was launched:

```
$ ps auxww|grep '[s]leep'
blair    79462   0.0  0.0   600908    744 s011  S+   11:17PM   0:00.00 sleep 1234567
```

using `lsof` shows which binary it ran:

```
$ lsof -p 79462 | awk '$4 == "txt" { print $9 }'
/opt/local-development/bin/gsleep
```

I have MacPorts coreutils +with_default_names installed, which explains that I picked up `gsleep` and not `/bin/sleep`.

Comment: Piping lsof output through awk works great, with one minor addition. I added `; exit` after the print statement so that only the first `txt` entry will be printed even if there are several as in the bash example.

Answer (score 3):

ps -ef with grep works for me.  For a specific file name, simply pipe through grep thus:

```
MacBook:~ Me$ ps -ef | grep Safari | grep -v grep
  501 15733   301   0   0:25.76 ??         1:58.24 /Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari -psn_0_4977855
```

(That final 'grep -v grep' simply stops you getting your own grep command in the output)

Comment: This worked in my case instead of `lsof -p $PID`, which was not returning any output for a PID associated with httpd.

Answer (score 2):

Example: you're after the associate process command name for `PID 45109`...

```
>    % ps awx | awk '$1 == 45109 { print $5 }'
>    /Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari
```

Comment: Will not show full binary path if binary was started just by name without specifying path.

Comment: doesn't work right, if path contains whitespace

Answer (score 2):

ps -p <pid> -Ocommand

```
L1A1:~ a1155344$ ps -p1 -Ocommand
  PID   TT  STAT      TIME COMMAND
    1   ??  Ss     0:02.26 /sbin/launchd
```

Answer (score 1):

try
ps aux